# Find Zip code from lat and long in geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps, zipcode

I am using Geocoder to find Zip code.

My code:

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

       try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

  if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getPostalCode()).append("\n");

   }
   myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
  else{
   myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
 }
```

My Problem is Zip code returns null.

And this code is not working in android 4.2 or Below version.

If there is online api which gives zip code by giving lat long. Then please show me that also.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

Postal code (ZIP code for United States), if available, is:

```
 final String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Android API and the documentation of [`getPostalCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode()):

> Returns the postal code of the address, for example "94110", or null
>   if it is unknown.

The simple yet sad answer is that there is no data of the postalcode for the given address. It is hard to recommend any other choice then the `Geocoder`, the `Google Geocoder API` is probably the source of the `Geocoder` in Android and I don't think there is better choices out there (for world wide purposes). If the searches are limited to a specific country there might be other solutions such as [`uk-postcodes API`](http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api) for the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

find postal_code and formatted_address tags from json of google geocoder API. I hope that helps....